# Ajax working locally, but not on the webserver

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using custom LiveValidation functions to validate the uniqueness of user login and email.

Each function sends a POST request to checkLogin.php and checkEmail.php files. The return is jsonencoded (true/false) and passed back to the function.

The problem is, it all works on my local server but fails on a web server. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the console to spit out an error? Cause what you describe can be a numerious ammount of problems

Comment: Check the PHP log on the server for errors.

Comment: Why not do a step-by-step debugging? First ensure that the web server is handling requests in your checkLogin  and checkEmail scripts. If you don't find the mole this way, check server log

Comment: Is the server you call through AJAX still the same server as the one that feeds the page?

Comment: The server is handling the requests in both .php files and yes, it's the same server as the one that feeds the page. I'll check the error log as mentioned above.

Comment: I checked the logs and there's nothing special, only few failed includes, that are not connected with this case. I also checked the jQuery .ajaxError method but it does not trigger...